# How to match users based on same Sets

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, mobile, swiftui

I'm about to finish my App, similar to Tinder, but when I can't figure out how to match users based on their food likings, via their Sets of Food.
Is `.filter()` the way to go?

[Video showing user selection of Food and CardView](https://streamable.com/tyavbe)

`CardStack` will be the compilation of all `CardView` that will be presented to the user matched in its likings.

```
struct CardStack: View {
    var people: [Person]
    @State private var fullscreenMode: Bool = false
    
    var body: some View {
        ZStack {
            ForEach(people) { person in
                CardView(person: person, fullscreenMode: $fullscreenMode)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Meanwhile `Person` is the parameter taken on `CardView`, that the user will then match to.

```
struct Person: Hashable, Identifiable {
    var id = UUID().uuidString
    var foodLikings: Set<Food>
    
    init(id: UUID) {
        self.foodLikings = Set(arrayLiteral: Food(id: 3, name: "Empanadas", foodImage: ["empanadas"]), Food(id: 1, name: "Asado", foodImage: ["asado"]))
    }
}
```

Here's what the `Set<Food>` consists of:

```
struct Food: Identifiable, Hashable {
    
    var id: Int
    
    let name: String
    let foodImage: [String]
    
    // Equatable
    static func == (lhs: Food, rhs: Food) -> Bool {
        lhs.id == rhs.id
    }
}
```

All the available options for Food selection:

```
class FoodDataService {
    
    static let comidas: [Comida] = [
        Comida(
            id: 0,
            name: "Asado",
            foodImage: ["asado"]
        ),
        Food(
            id: 1,
            name: "Pizzas",
            foodImage: ["pizzas"]
        ),
        Food(
            id: 2,
            name: "Milanesas",
            foodImage: ["milanesas"]
        ),
        Food(
            id: 3,
            name: "Empanadas",
            foodImage: ["empanadas"]
        )
    }
```

And finally what the User's struct is made of:

```
var person: Person
var user: User
```

```
struct User {
    var foodLikings: Set<Food>
}
```

Comment: Have you looked at the documentation for [Set](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/set), there are several functions available for comparing two sets?

Comment: I tried using `isDisjoint` and if false, ``people`` would be presented to user, but it didn't work since they did share one food in common but it didn't show them

Comment: Are you saying this is a problem with your view and not about how to use Set?

Comment: I guess yes since Disjoint should mean if both set don't share even one thing in common

Answer (score 0):

Found a much easier way to match users by simply using `.contains()`.

```
if favoriteList.contains(personFavoriteList) {
                // Show matched people
            } else {
                // Show other
            }
```

Where `personFavoriteList` and `favoriteList` are strings returned as their likings mapped and sorted.

Comment: I doubt this will work but maybe I misunderstood the question.